# select li click capybara class

Tags: select, click, html-lists, capybara

I'm trying to select the i class icon of Twitter from the li list.

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-account_id_some_number" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true">
  <img src="/photo.jpg?793844">
  <span class="account-name">Twitter-1</span>
  <i class="icon-Twitter center-vertical"></i>
</li>
```

So if I select the first one, it works. How can I select the one I want. For example, if it's twitter, which could be the 1st or 2nd or 3rd element. I want to target just the icon with Twitter, then click it.

```
first('.select2-results__option').click
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find('i.icon-Twitter').click
```

will click the actual icon, which is inside the <li> you want and should trigger the li click handler.  You could also trigger off the text with something like

```
find('li.select2-results__option', text: 'Twitter-1').click
```

which will click the desired <li> based on the visible text in it